# cocos2d scheduler interval vs delay

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to understand the difference between interval and delay in cocos2d's scheduler.

If delay is the time between 2 selectors get executed. What is interval really?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments in cocos2D CCNode.h file, may be useful.

Schedules a custom selector with an interval time in seconds
/**
repeat will execute the action repeat + 1 times, for a continues action use kCCRepeatForever
delay is the amount of time the action will wait before execution
*/

If the selector is already scheduled, then the interval parameter will be updated without scheduling it again.

```
-(void) schedule:(SEL)selector interval:(ccTime)interval repeat: (uint) repeat delay:(ccTime) delay;
```